# How to set readonly property only for edit grid window columns?

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

i am doing my project using **struts2** and **hibernate** and i am using **jqgrid** for data display. Now i want to set **readonly** property for id field on the editGrid window. but not for add window. My sample code

```xml
<sjg:grid id="gridtable"
    caption="Customer List"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="customerList"
    rowNum="10"
    autowidth="true"
    editurl="%{editurl}"
    editinline="false"
    navigator="true"
    navigatorAdd="true"
    navigatorAddOptions="
        {
            viewPagerButtons:false,
            recreateForm:true,
            checkOnUpdate:true,
            closeAfterAdd:true
        }"
    navigatorDelete="true"
    navigatorEdit="true"
    navigatorRefresh="true"
    navigatorSearch="true"
    navigatorEditOptions="
        {
            viewPagerButtons:false,
            recreateForm:true,
            checkOnUpdate:true,
            closeAfterEdit:true
        }"
    navigatorDeleteOptions="{ checkOnUpdate:true}"
    navigatorViewOptions="
        {
            viewPagerButtons:false,
            recreateForm: true,
            checkOnUpdate: true
        }"
    navigatorSearchOptions="{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt','in','ni','cn','nc']}"
    navigatorView="true"
    rownumbers="true"
    rowList="10,20,30"
    viewrecords="true"
>
<sjg:gridColumn
    name="id"
    align="left"
    key="true"
    index="id"
    title="Customer id"
    sortable="false"
    editable="true"
    editrules="{
        number: true,
        required: true
    }"
    edittype="text" />
<sjg:gridColumn
    name="custName"
    align="left"
    index="custName"
    title="Customer Name"
    sortable="false"
    editable="true"
    edittype="text" />
    ......
</sjg:grid>
```

can i call `beforeShowForm` and `afterShowForm` functions inside the **navigatorEditOption**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not not struts2 defeloper, so what I suggest could be not correct. Nevertheless you can try to include inline JavaScript code directly inside the **navigatorEditOption**:

```
navigatorViewOptions="
                {
                    viewPagerButtons:false,
                    recreateForm: true,
                    checkOnUpdate: true,
                    beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
                        alert("inside of beforeShowForm function");
                    }
                }"
```

It looks close to the code from [the page](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/NavigatorButtons) of documentation. I hope it will work.

Alternatively you can define some **global** function like

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myBeforeShowForm = function ($form) {
            alert("inside of beforeShowForm function");
        };
</script>
```

and use global `myBeforeShowForm` inside of **navigatorEditOption**:

```
navigatorViewOptions="
                {
                    viewPagerButtons:false,
                    recreateForm: true,
                    checkOnUpdate: true,
                    beforeShowForm: myBeforeShowForm
                }"
```

(compare with the code of `datePick` function on [the page](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SearchGrid))

Comment: hello Oleg. thanks for your answer. may i know what is form? is it grid id(gridtable) or html form id(<form id="frm">)?

Comment: @SugunaSs: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand your question: "may i know what is form?" What you mean? If you mean `$form` parameters of `beforeShowForm` then it's jQuery wrapper of the form: like `$("#"+formId)`.

Comment: ya. it is solved now. i am using second way. and now i set readonly property to my edit grid window columns by $("#gridtable").jqGrid('setColProp','id',{editoptions:{ readonly: 'readonly'}}); thank you once again.